# How to block all website ips using netsh?

Tags: javascript, electron, firewall, netsh

I'v been trying to block all ips of a specific website using netsh advfirewall for an Electron JavaScript application. Here is my code.

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const { exec } = require('child_process')
const dns = require('dns')
const url = require('url')

const createWindow = () => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600
  })

  win.loadFile('Screens/index.html')
  blockWebsite('littlebigsnake.com')
  win.setMenu(null)
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
})

function blockWebsite(urlString) {
  // grab host name from input
  const { hostname } = url.parse(`http://${urlString}`)
  // turn hostname into all ips
  dns.resolve(hostname, 'A', (err, addresses) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(`Error: ${err}`)
      return
    }

    // block each ip address through the firewall
    addresses.forEach(address => {
      exec(`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Block ${urlString}" dir=out action=block remoteip=${address}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(`${error}`)
          return
        }
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`)
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`)
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Here is the error I am getting
Error: Command failed: netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Block littlebigsnake.com" dir=out action=block remoteip=104.26.9.138

Error: Command failed: netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Block littlebigsnake.com" dir=out action=block remoteip=172.67.71.90

Error: Command failed: netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Block littlebigsnake.com" dir=out action=block remoteip=104.26.8.138

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
const blockWebsite = (website) => {
  const command = `echo 127.0.0.1 ${website} >> C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts`
  exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`${error}`)
      return
    }
    console.log(`Success: ${stdout}`)
  })
}
```

Just write the website url to hosts file. The hosts file will then redirect all outgoing attempts to this website into a crash(not quite, but close enough). I can't get it working without admin privileges however. So you need to run as admin.